# c++11: assigning global STL "map<string, string>" with initializer_list crashes in VS2015

Tags: c++, c++11

Does anybody know why this code crashes on "map" line with error message:"Debug assert failed: invalid null point" ?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

map<string, string> VarZeroTable = {
    { "bool",      "false" },
    { "int",       "0" },
    { "char",      '\0' },
    { "float",     "0.0"},
    { "double",    "0.0"},
    { "string",    "\"\"" },
    { "short",     "0" },
    { "long",      "0" },
    { "uint64_t",  "0" },
    { "uint32_t",  "0" },
    { "uint16_t",  "0" },
    { "uint8_t",   "0" },
    { "uintmax_t", "0" },
    { "int8_t",    "0" },
    { "int16_t",   "0" },
    { "int32_t",   "0" },
    { "int64_t",   "0" },
    { "intptr_t",  "nullptr" },
    { "uintptr_t", "uintptr_t" },
    { "size_t",    "0" },
    { "ptrdiff_t", "0"}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int count = VarZeroTable.count("int64_t");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiler and exact version?  Does it happen when you remove `'\0' `?  [Mcve] woukd be appreciated; delete lines until minimal yet still reproduces error.

Comment: { "char",      '\0' },

Answer (score 6):

The code is crashing because you're initializing a `std::string` with a `char` of value `'\0'`.

Since there is no constructor of `std::string` which takes a single `char`, the closest constructor that matches is apparently the one that takes a `const char*` pointer. Since `'\0'` is a literal with the value 0 (null), null ends up being passed to the pointer parameter, and it crashes during initialization.

You can force the creation of a string with a single character in it by using an initializer list for that `std::string`:

```
// ...
{ "char",      { '\0' } },
// ...
```

Comment: ahh... you are right!  I missed that...

Comment: Wouldn't just using `""` do the job?

Comment: fixed: http://rextester.com/YMIIV66239

Comment: Why was the one taking `const char*` picked up, instead of the one taking `size_type` ? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: @François: `""` does include an implicit NULL at the end, but the string constructed from it would be a zero-length string (also with an implicit NULL). However, a string explicitly constructed with a single NULL character is a one-length string, consisting of the NULL, additionally followed by the implicit NULL.

Comment: @nodakai: The one that takes `size_type` also takes a second parameter (for the character to repeat that many times).

Comment: @Cameron :facepalm: silly me... thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Changed:

```
{ "char",      '\0' },
```

To:

```
{ "char",      "'\\0'" },
```

Tricky on the eyes this morning...

Comment: Do you understand that `"'\\0'"` makes the string actually contain 4 characters: `'\0'`?

Comment: that was the intent... my eyes were just confused because it was next to char keyword...   put me in char mode instead of string mode..

Comment: @fran OP disagrees.  ;)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Thanks, didn't realize that was OP.